# How to delete table row on button click in React

Tags: reactjs

I wrote an application in React to get value from database, and display its elements in table. It works fine. But my problem is that when I click on delete button in addDelete function, it deletes the content not in the expected way ( I want to delete row sittuated previous to the button). I tryed most of approaches from stack overflow but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
    import './App.css';
    import {Users} from "./users";
    import {Email} from "./emails";
    import React, {Component} from "react";
    import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 

export class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
 this.state = {
    users: [],
    rows: [{}],
    data: [],
    products: []
};
this.addChild= this.addChild.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((Response) => Response.json())
  .then((findresponse) =>
  {
  this.setState({
    users:findresponse
   })
  //console.log(this.state.users);
  });

  }

 addChild = (product) => {
   if(this.state.products.indexOf(product.name) === -1){
   this.setState({ products: [...this.state.products, product]})
   }
 }

addDelete = (i, j) => {

    var items = this.state.users;
     const index = items.indexOf(items[i]);
          if (index > -1) {
            items.splice(index, 1);
          }
              this.setState({
                items: items
              });
          }
render(){


  return (
   <>
   <div className="App">
    <main>
       
    <Users callback = {this.addChild} />
      <table className = 'list1 table-sm table-striped'>
        <thead><tr><th>Name and surname</th><th>Email address</th><th>Delete</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>

         { this.state.users.map(person=><tr className ='name1' key = {person.id}><td>
          {person.name}
   
           </td>
           <td>
           {person.email}
           </td>
             <td>
             <button key = {person.id} onClick={this.addDelete.bind(null, person.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
              </td></tr>)}
        
            {
               this.state.person === 0 
               ? <div className = 'text-center'>There is no persons</div>
               : <Email key = {this.state.products.id} products = {this.state.products} />
             }
             
        </tbody>
        </table>
     </main>
   </div>
    </>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You are mutating the original array. Maybe that's the reason. try this `var items = [...this.state.users];`

Comment: Also you are mistakenly using `indexOf` which is used with `string`, instead of using `findIndex`, which is used with `array`.

Comment: Tryed it. But it doesn't delete items. Gives no action on button click.

Comment: Are you passing `id` of the product or `index` of it in the array?. if you are passing index then, you can directly pass it to the `splice`, without even using `findIndex`

Comment: Like:  items.splice(i, 1);
              
                  this.setState({
                    items: items
                  }); I Tryed it but deletes in non expected way.

Comment: yes. just like that. A note, it is always recommended to pass the `id` of the product instead of passing `index`. Because if your array items change order, you end up deleting the wrong product.